# Use PopupMenu to choose a treatment

Tags: dynamic, popup

I have a list of treatments:

```
treatmentsNames={"walk","run","fly","swim","dream"}
```

I want to use this list to populate a PopupMenu. The number of treatments can change at runtime. If I choose the first treatment I want to get a value 1, if second then 2 and so on. It does not matter what their names are.

How do I implement this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[123];
max = 5;
choices = RandomWord["Verb", max]
wts = Range[max]
pdata = AssociationThread[choices, wts]
```

> ```
> <|"obtrude" -> 1, "enrich" -> 2, "seam" -> 3, "chap" -> 4, 
>  "hurdle" -> 5|>
> ```

```
x = RandomChoice[Keys@pdata]
{PopupMenu[
  Dynamic[x], Keys@pdata]
 , Dynamic[pdata[x]]
 }
```

---

If you are already using a `DynamicModule` then:

```
DynamicModule[{x0 = RandomChoice[Keys@pdata]},
 {PopupMenu[Dynamic[x0], Keys@pdata]
  , Dynamic[pdata[x0]]
  }
 ]
```